# Flutter Web Tests: Assertion failed: "Parent #123 has child #115. However, the child is attached to #119."

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test, gherkin

When I run automated integration tests via [flutter gherkin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gherkin) on the Chrome Browser (via Chromedriver), I get the following error:

[image]

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Assertion failed: "Parent #123 has child #115. However, the child is attached to #119."

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 251:49  throw_
lib/_engine/engine/semantics/semantics.dart 1601:15                           <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13      forEach
lib/_engine/engine/semantics/semantics.dart 1585:22                           <fn>
lib/_engine/engine/semantics/semantics.dart 1615:14                           updateSemantics
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 623:35                            updateSemantics
packages/flutter_test/src/window.dart 380:24                                  updateSemantics
packages/flutter/src/semantics/semantics.dart 3056:22                         sendSemanticsUpdate
packages/flutter/src/rendering/object.dart 1076:7                             flushSemantics
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 502:21                            drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 883:13                              drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 363:5                             [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1145:15                           [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1082:9                            handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter_test/src/binding.dart 1450:30                                handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 996:5                             [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1005:13                           invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 159:5                             invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine.dart 455:45                                                <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1444:13                                          _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1335:19                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1244:7                                           runUnaryGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1281:26                                          <fn>
```

This does not happen on Android, or another device. This is also appearing only after some time, so not at the beginning. So if I run only a single test, one by one, they are executed correctly. Nothing in this StackTrace leads to an error in my code.

Dependencies:

- flutter: 2.8.1

  - flutter_test: sdk: flutter
  - integration_test: sdk: flutter
- dart: 2.15.1
- test: 1.17.10
- test_api: 0.4.3
- flutter_gherkin: ^3.0.0-rc.9

See Sources:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2.8.1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L4647
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2.8.1/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart#L1450
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2.8.1/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/window.dart#L380

Comment: I now created an issue at flutter with the according code example:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97606

Answer (score 2):

Disabling semantics during the test run fixed the issue for me:

```
testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    ...
}, semanticsEnabled: false);
```